# Not able to fetch particular url in java

Tags: java

I have been using following function for fetching and parsing URLs.

```
public static void getPage(String url_string, String page)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(url_string);
        System.out.println(url.getPort() + " " + url.getDefaultPort());
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(page));
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
           bw.write(line + "\n");
        }
        bw.close();
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Page fetched in "+page);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
        System.out.println("\nError while fetching the page - ");
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I call it as -

```
getPage("http://google.com", "tmp.html");
```

I am able to fetch any type of URLs but not able to fetch this particular URL.

```
http://www.toysrus.com/storefrontsearch/stores.jsp?skuId=13112916&quantity=1&postalCode=79414&productId=13066123&searchRadius=10000
```

Though we can see this page on Firefox and Chrome. It is not showing up here also:

```
http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html
```

Comment: Your `catch` block displays a stack trace.  If that is happening, could you share it with us?

Comment: That URL returns nothing for me on firefox or chrome, indicating that the site likely sets a cookie on a previous page, then checks for it before returning the results (probably an anti-scraping measure).

Comment: @ajb No error thrown so nothing in catch ...

Comment: @jedwards I have cleared cookies ... but I guess it is setting cookies during first call ... I will check regarding this and reply ... thnx

Comment: you can try with [apache common](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html)

Comment: Be sure to format your code for StackedOverflow. The tabbing in your original code was hard to read. It also helps if you stay within the minimum width before it adds on a scrollbar. I edited your post to give you the idea.

Comment: @qzcx Thanks .. I will take care next time.

Comment: @jedwards Thanks man for the great HINT... got the solution. It was setting "ispuStoreSearch" and "postalCode" cookies when we first call and then onwards it was taking those values. Hence, when we refresh page we get the page. Now I am setting cookies before calling. Thats it :) How Can I vote up your comment ??

Comment: @user2952821, happy it helped!  If you hover over a comment, you'll see a gray up arrow and flag appear to the left of it -- if you click the up arrow it'll get upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

`http://google.com` sends a HTTP 302 Statuscode wich means that the location is not available (for now). But you receive a new location in the header data.

You can parse the header of the answer an get the new URL from the field `location`. Try to open this new URL.

You should always check the header data of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to drkunibar, I would say to examine the headers. You can do this in both Chrome and Firefox.  In Chrome, open tools>developer_tools and switch to the network tab. Then load the webpage. By clicking on the request, you can examine everything about it. If you don't see anything strange, then I would try examining it in a debugger. Good Luck!